# TerrainTexture missing in unityplayer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I launch my game in the Unity player, the texture of my terrain is gone (image 1). When I launch the same scene in the editor, it looks as it should (image 2).

I add the texture with this code:

```
terrainData.alphamapResolution = 500;
SplatPrototype[] terrainTexture = new SplatPrototype[2];
terrainTexture[0] = new SplatPrototype();
terrainTexture[0].texture = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("MyTexture/GrassHillAlbedo");
terrainTexture[1] = new SplatPrototype();
terrainTexture[1].texture = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("MyTexture/SandAlbedo");
terrainData.splatPrototypes = terrainTexture;

float[,,] splatMapData = new float[terrainData.alphamapWidth, terrainData.alphamapHeight, 2];

for (int x = 0; x < terrainData.alphamapWidth; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < terrainData.alphamapHeight; y++)
    {
        // Grasland
        if (biomes[x, y] == 0)
        {
            splatMapData[x, y, 0] = 1;
            splatMapData[x, y, 1] = 0;
        }

        // Desert
        if (biomes[x, y] == 1)
        {
            splatMapData[x, y, 0] = 0;
            splatMapData[x, y, 1] = 1;
        }
    }
}

terrainData.SetAlphamaps(0, 0, splatMapData);
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to enable "write/read" on the texture.